# given an image mask, how do I generate a path corresponding to that mask?

Tags: image-processing, graphics

I have a representation of an image mask as a 2d array of 0s and 1s (where 0s are pixels of the image which are not masked and 1s are pixels of the image which are masked).  For example,

`00100
01110
11111`

(a triangle with vertices at (0,2), (2,0) and (2,4))

What I want is to convert this 2d array to a path corresponding to the shape.  In this case an SVG path would be something like `M 0 2 L 2 0 L 2 4 L 0 2`.  The shapes can be arbitrarily complex.

Is this task something which is commonly done?  Does it have a name?  What are some libraries which can do this (in any language)?  I'm not looking for actual code, but rather for pointers of where to go to learn how to do this.  I tried Googling for related keywords but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simples and the fastest methods is [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares)

You can also find many [sorces of it](https://gist.github.com/mieko/3c17c41b8be9f2598c12)

Answer (score 0):

Found the description of the technique in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing